# C# Linq XML GroupBy OrderBy get count

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this xml structure and I need the count of non empty work and home elements, groupby Country attribute and then orderby country attribute.

Something like Dictionary>, but I fail with the linq expression. At the moment the list is only filtered, groupby and orderby. Missing part is the count non empty work and home elements.
Is it possible to do it immendantly in the query or should use after query the list?

XMLFile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Region ID="NA">
        <Name>QWERTZ</Name>
        <Country ID="1">
            <Facility Name="1">
                <Department Name="1">
                    <Member Name="1">
                        <Home>555-666</Home>
                        <Work>111-666</Work>
                    </Member>
                </Department>
            </Facility>
        </Country>      
    </Region>
        <Region ID="CHINA">
        <Name>ASDF</Name>
        <Country ID="2">
            <Facility Name="2">
                <Department Name="2">
                    <Member Name="2">
                        <Home>111-222</Home>
                        <Work>111-222</Work>
                    </Member>
                </Department>
            </Facility>
        </Country>      
    </Region>
    <Region ID="EU">
        <Name>ASDF</Name>
        <Country ID="3">
            <Facility Name="3">
                <Department Name="1">
                    <Member Name="1">
                        <Home>111-222</Home>
                        <Work></Work>
                    </Member>
                </Department>
            </Facility>
        </Country>      
    </Region>
</Root>
```

Method

```
 public static List<IGrouping<string,XElement>> getgrouped(string filename)
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(filename);

    return xml.Root
        .Descendants("Country")
        .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("ID").Value)
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each Descendant I project an object with the country id and the number of non empty Descendant `Work` and `Home` elements. Then I `GroupBy` and sum up the counters.

```
xml.Root.Descendants("Country")
    .Select(element => new 
    {
        Id = (string) element.Attribute("ID").Value,
        NonEmptyWork = element.Descendants("Work")
                              .Count(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.Value)),
        NonEmptyHome = element.Descendants("Home")
                              .Count(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.Value))
    })
    .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
    .Select(g => new
    { 
        Id = g.Key, 
        NonEmptyWorkAmount = g.Sum(item => item.NonEmptyWork), 
        NonEmptyHomeAmount = g.Sum(item => item.NonEmptyHome)
    })
    .OrderBy(item => item.Id)
    .ToList();
```

To output it as a dictionary instead of `ToList`:

```
    // Dictionary<string, YourType>
    .ToDictionary( key => key.Id, value => value);
```

Comment: Id = (string)x.Attribute("ID").Value X is unkown,   .Count(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.InnerText)) w.innertext is unknown too, but you gave the right direction to understand.

Comment: Have to find the solve button, but one more question I have related to your solution. If i would like to select into <t>, then I get inaccesable due protectlevel, but the class is public and the properties are public with get and set

Comment: @Shazter - About the marking solved then under to the number of votes of the answer there is a grey V to press (turns green). About the second question I'll have to see some code - but also... followup question should be posted as separate questions.. If you can't solve that error then post a question and if you want tag me in a comment I'll try and help :)